# Return a String from a Handler.. from a Service

Tags: android, service, handler

Here's my app layout.

```
    MainActivity
    |
    Service
    |__Handler
       |__Runnable
```

In the Runnable I retrieve a String from the internet. It's small enough to fit in an intent, if that matters.
I want to pass the String all the way back to MainActivity and notify it that it has been updated.

How can I do this?

Comment: Make a broadcast or simply start that MainActivity with the result as Extra String.

Comment: How can I connect the incoming receiver to the outgoing? There seem to be some scope issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods:

1. Make a broadcast from Runnable
2. Start the MainActivity from Runnable

Both require to put the result as String Extra, in the Intent.

I suppose your Handler and Runnable are inline-class under Service, so you can have access to the `Context`. If not, you have to pass the Service Context to those classes.

```
> There seem to be some scope issues.
```

Nope, any class can call `Context.sendBroadcast` or `Context.startActivity`, and it does not require to be done on the Main Thread.

Comment: I think I have everything set up right, including the manifest. But I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException whenever I send the broadcast: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stevenschoen.appname.MainActivity.IncomingReceiver     (names changed) Where am I supposed to put the IncomingReceiver class?

Comment: You can create the Receiver as inner class within the Activity, and call registerReceiver() for it (remember to unregister upon Acitivty.onStop() ). Downside is if you activity get killed you won't receive the result.